# Python создать ZIP архив с паролем

Tags: python, поиск-библиотек, zip

Подскажите пожалуйста с помощью какой библиотеки можно создать зип архив с паролем на python и конкретный код для примера, как это сделать?

Comment: Что вы уже сами нарыли по этому поводу?

Comment: Вот так делаю  ```from crocodile.toolbox import Path Path(r'C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\file.csv').zip(pwd="lol", use_7z=True)```  - создает 7z архив с паролем.

Comment: @ЕкатеринаКорчагина пробовали `use_7z=False` ставить?

Comment: Если 'use_7z=False' - архив не создается

Answer (score 2):

Вариант

```
import pyminizip

infile = "./text.txt"
outfile = "./output.zip"
password = "123456"
compress_lvl = 5
  
# compressing file
pyminizip.compress(infile, None, outfile, password, compress_lvl)
```